# insanely long classpath

Tags: java

I am trying to add the following classpath nicely to windows, but I don't know how. All this files are in the same folder, but it just doesn't work if I set my classpath variable to .;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib*.jar.

This one doesn't work either:

```
.;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\Bib2HTML.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\GnuGetOpt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\activation.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\ant-contrib-1.0b2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\ant-junit.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\ant-launcher.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\ant-nodeps.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\ant.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\bcmail-jdk15-1.45.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\bcprov-jdk15-1.45.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\commons-compress-1.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\commons-discovery-0.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\commons-fileupload-1.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\commons-io-1.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\commons-lang-2.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\concurrent.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\fontbox-1.1.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\gate-asm.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\gate-compiler-jdt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\gateHmm.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec-1.1.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\icu4j.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\jakarta-oro-2.0.5.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\javacc.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\jaxb-api-2.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\jaxen-1.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\jaxws-api-2.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\jdom.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\jempbox-1.1.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\junit.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\log4j-1.2.14.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\lubm.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\lucene-core-3.0.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\mail.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\nekohtml-1.9.14.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\ontotext.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\pdfbox-1.1.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\pg73jdbc3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\poi-3.6.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\poi-ooxml-3.6.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.6.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\poi-scratchpad-3.6.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\spring-aop-2.0.8.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\spring-beans-2.0.8.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\spring-core-2.0.8.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\stax-api-1.0.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\tika-core-0.7.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\tika-parsers-0.7.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\wstx-lgpl-3.2.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\xercesImpl.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\xmlunit-1.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\xpp3-1.1.3.3_min.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\xstream-1.2.jar
```

How do I add all these jars to the classpath

Ted

Comment: What is the error message you get?  Are you properly quoting or escaping spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to say `C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE-6.0\lib\*` (appropriately quoted of course.)

Refer to ["Setting the class path"](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) for details.  Specifically read the section entitled "Understanding class path wildcards".

Comment: ARgg.. you're right my error was somewhere else I think. is there a way to know whether this things are being picked up without a program that uses them?

Comment: I don't know.  The `-verbose:class` option might help, though that just reports the classes that are used, I think.  Otherwise, you could try to load specific resources or classes, or list the classloader's Packages.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use quotes when you have spaces in a file name for the command line, like

```
"C:/Program Files/..."
```

else `C:/Program` will be interpreted as a separate arguments from `Files/...`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try putting some other jar and using it in Java program from location where you are trying to run the app/program which will use all this libraries. I think this will digonose the problem that is this class path variable is used by jdk or not.

Answer (score 0):

If your classpath is insanely long you might consider writing your own classloader to dynamically load jars or .class files.  It's actually not that hard to do and could simplify things.